# How to exclude the top row in a .dat file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a `.dat` file in python.

I am accessing two columns:

`v, bv = np.loadtxt("Hyades.dat",usecols=(1,8),unpack=True)`

However, I am also getting the headings of the two columns. How can I exclude them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip rows by setting an integer to the argumen skiprows. Example:

```py
v, bv = np.loadtxt("Hyades.dat",usecols=(1,8),unpack=True,skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have fixed the original issue but now it says `vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]` and gives `IndexError: list index out of range`